# opencv cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS cuts out parts of my image

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, camera

I'm using opencv in python3 on a raspberry pi compute model 4 with two cameras. I want to capture the video from the camera with 90 fps. That works fine, but for whatever reason opencv decides to cut a lot from my image when I my desired fps exceeds 40, which is a problem for me.

[A captured video from a camera with 40 fps (or lower)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrsQi.png)

[The same camera with 41 fps (or higher)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tC2eg.png)

Here is my code, right now it is just supposed to show a window with the video of the camera:

```
import cv2
import time

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 41)

width = 640
height = 480
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)

while True:
    check, frame = cam.read()

    cv2.imshow('video', frame)
    
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key == 27:
        break
    
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I didn't find any useful options in the opencv documentation, so I hope you can help me.

I tried to lower the resolution but that didn't change anything.

Comment: cameras have video "modes". consult the data sheet. it specifies the cropping and binning for each mode. -- **not** an OpenCV problem. you can reproduce this with any other camera application.

Comment: You didn't say which cameras you are using, nor which OS.

Comment: You could try `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` and `v4l2-ctl --list-formats`